# What counts as a boss for Nephalem Valor?

Tags: diablo-iii

When you have stacks of Nephalem Valor bosses drop significantly more loot ([Source](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Nephalem_Valor)). What sort of monsters drop extra loot (not just more magical loot from the magic find, but an increased number of items)?

I've noticed the Warden and the Butcher dropping an increased number of items with Nephalem Valor but I haven't seen blue or yellow mobs dropping more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is safe to assume that the [Act bosses](http://www.diablowiki.net/Boss) count as bosses, but what is less clear is if free range bosses count.  The Act bosses are:

> **Act I**
>
> Skeleton king. Araneae. The Warden. Butcher.
>
> **Act II**
>
> Magda. Zoltun Kulle. Belial.
>
> **Act III**
>
> Ghom. Siegebreaker Assault Beast. Cydaea. Azmodan.
>
> **Act IV**
>
> Rakanoth. Diablo.

Free range bosses are also described at that link, but it will take research by someone at 60 to answer whether they count (and I am not yet 60).  I would note that champions and uniques should not be expected to count, as they are specifically mention differently in the [Blizzard post](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4241234476).

Comment: I tried to use the spoiler tag, but as usual Markdown hates me.

Comment: Ah interesting, I did not realize the warden was in the same category as the skeleton king.

Comment: Izual does not count as a boss for Nephalem Valor.

Answer (score 3):

The complete list of bosses with a 'bonus pool' for Nephalem Valor is as follows:

## Act I

- The Skeleton King
- Queen Araneae
- The Warden
- Butcher

## Act II

- Maghda
- Zolton Kulle
- Belial

## Act 3

- Ghom
- Siegebreaker Assault Beast
- Cydaea
- Azmodean

## Act 4

- Izual
- Diablo

You'll note that, with the exception of the Warden, the main thing these all have in common is that they have a dedicated 'boss chamber' in which the fight occurs, which you cannot leave once the fight begins, which makes them easy to identify.

Comment: Did you have a source? or is this from experience?

Comment: Source, yes. Linkable, no. Sorry.

Comment: Izual does not count as a boss for this, rather Rakanoth does.

Answer (score -2):

*Everything* counts for Nephalem Valor drops.  See the original Blizzard announcement [here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4241234476).

The primary mechanism of Nephalem Valor is that it increases magic find and gold find by 25% both.  So every loot drop including blue and gold mobs, but also even white mobs and chests are affected by Nephalem Valor.

Comment: I realize a large part of the Nephalem Valor is the magic find, but as I state in the question I'm looking for the bosses that drop extra items (not higher quality ones) based on your Valor stack. As shown here: http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/u6e2p/nephalem_valor_some_data_on_boss_drop_rates/ The feature I'm asking about was described in more detail here: http://www.diablofans.com/topic/37479-nephalem-valor-buff/

Comment: From the Blizz post: "As an extra reward, if you kill a boss while this buff is active, you’ll receive extra loot drops from that boss."  That is what Rapida is referring to.